# How can we use bootstrap-sweetalert library in angular2 or 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert

I use bootstrap-sweetalert library in my project.
First I install using below codes

```
   `bower install bootstrap-sweetalert --save`
```

Then i add the the path to angular-cli.json file

```
 "scripts"          : [
    "../bower_components/bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.js" 
    ],
```

In assets directory there is a `styles.css` file and i add the below code

```
  @import "../../../bower_components/bootstrap-sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css";
```

Html file is as

```
 <button class="btn btn-circle green-haze btn-outline sbold uppercase mt-sweetalert" data-title="Sweet Alerts with Icons" data-message="Success Icon" data-type="success" data-allow-outside-click="true"
                          data-confirm-button-class="btn-success">Icon Success Alert</button>
```

But it does not work!... 
In addition, I add an alert() in the sweetalert.js file and it works !

But html file does not work.

Is there any way to work ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the styles in your `index.html`. I will show you my example with simple bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

This is the index.html that has this in it:

```
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

Remember to import this library after the main libraries.

Also, keep checking the documentation:

- https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/
- https://github.com/lipis/bootstrap-sweetalert#sweetalert-for-bootstrap

Good luck and good coding!